# How do I add conditions in a WHERE SQL clause or return all results if filters are empty

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have an SQL statement with a WHERE clause where I am adding additional filters if a variable passed into the stored procedure IN parameter is a certain value.

The IN parameter is called filterID and can be empty if I need all records, or have the value SEN,EAL or MAGT if I want to only select the records which have IDs in those columns from the LEFT JOINED tables.

This is the extract from the SQL query to show the joining of the tables and the additional filter.

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_sen ON tbl_pupil.pupilID = tbl_sen.pupilID 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_eal ON tbl_pupil.pupilID = tbl_eal.pupilID  
        LEFT JOIN tbl_magt ON tbl_pupil.pupilID = tbl_magt.pupilID
        WHERE 
        tbl_test.schoolID=schoolID
        AND (
            (filterID='SEN' AND tbl_sen.senID IS NOT NULL) OR 
            (filterID='EAL' AND tbl_eal.ealID IS NOT NULL) OR
            (filterID='MAGT' AND tbl_magt.magtID IS NOT NULL))
        AND tbl_test.import=1;
```

WHen I execute the stored procedure with the values, it shows the correct results. However, if I don't want to add the filter and pass filterID as empty/NULL, it returns 0 results when I need it to return ALL the results.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks Stu, if that's what I need to do, I've got plenty of learning to do in dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
...
AND CASE filterID WHEN 'SEN' THEN tbl_sen.senID IS NOT NULL
                  WHEN 'EAL' THEN tbl_eal.ealID IS NOT NULL
                  WHEN 'MAGT' THEN tbl_magt.magtID IS NOT NULL
                  ELSE filterID IS NULL END
AND ...
```

As I understand the `filterID` is local variable (SP parameter) so there is no problem to use it twice (rather than bound parameter of the query - in this case you may use user-defined intermediate variable).

[Simplified DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a7de607d6ccd293a55231bdbf5708f6)

Comment: This makes total sense...although I add it in and the query still returns no results. Whereas if I remove the filterID option completely, it returns lots of records....will persevere.

Comment: @petworthnick Fiddle added.

Comment: That is very clear, thank you. When I execute the SP in phpmyadmin, it returns, nothing. However...if I run the SQL CALL sp_test(3,14,26,NULL) (Where the NULL value is the filterID) it is returning the records. This looks hopeful as this is how I'll be calling it from PHP. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Based on what you've helped me with here....I'm applied it to another filter I'm using. I use the line:
CASE progressVal
WHEN ('wellbelow' OR 'muchlower') THEN tbl_progress.progress='Much lower than expected'
ELSE progressVal IS NULL
END

However, I get a warning saying:

Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'wellbelow'
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'muchlower'

Do I have to separte them out, or is there a bettter fix? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
AND (
    (filterID='SEN' AND tbl_sen.senID IS NOT NULL) OR 
    (filterID='EAL' AND tbl_eal.ealID IS NOT NULL) OR
    (filterID='MAGT' AND tbl_magt.magtID IS NOT NULL) OR
    (filterID IS NULL)
)
```